# How to check if a string is an rgb hex string

Tags: python, string, function, hex, block

I am trying to create a way to proofread command console input and check to make sure that the string is an rgb hex string. (Ex: #FAF0E6)  Currently I am working with a try: except: block.

```
def isbgcolor(bgcolor):
    #checks to see if bgcolor is binary
    try:
        float(bgcolor)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

I tried also using a .startswith('#').  I have seen examples of how to write this function in Java but I'm still a beginner and Python's all I know. Help?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "binary", but checking to see whether it's a valid float representation doesn't seem to match any meaning for "binary" I can think of, and it's certainly not what you want here—`#FAF0E6` is not even close to a float representation, and a float representation like `1.23e6` is not even close to an RGB hex string.

Comment: valib rgb hex for what?  css, for example, will accept #fff

Comment: You should remove "#" and pass it into `int(text.replace("#", ''), 16)`

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: I think `text[1:]` or `text.lstrip('#')` is probably clearer, and it also avoids handling invalid color strings like `1###`.

Comment: @abarnert, this is from a function that worked for proofreading strings, I thought I'd try to convert it somehow to make this function work.

Comment: What do you mean by "proofreading strings"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, the best way to see if a string matches some simple format is to actually try to parse it. (Especially if you're only checking so you can then parse it if valid, or print an error if not.) So, let's do that.

The standard library is full of all kinds of useful things, so it's always worth searching. If you want to parse a hex string, the first thing that comes up is [`binascii.unhexlify`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify). We want to unhexlify everything after the first `#` character. So:

```
import binascii

def parse_bgcolor(bgcolor):
    if not bgcolor.startswith('#'):
        raise ValueError('A bgcolor must start with a "#"')
    return binascii.unhexlify(bgcolor[1:])

def is_bgcolor(bgcolor):
    try:
        parse_bgcolor(bgcolor)
    except Exception as e:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

This accepts 3-character hex strings (but then so do most data formats that use `#`-prefixed hex RGB), and even 16-character ones. If you want to add a check for the length, you can add that. Is the rule `== 6` or `in (3, 6)` or `% 3 == 0`? I don't know, but presumably you do if you have a rule you want to add.

If you start using `parse_bgcolor`, you'll discover that it's giving you a `bytes` with 6 values from 0-255, when you really wanted 3 values from 0-65535. You can combine them manually, or you can parse each two-character pair as a number (e.g., with `int(pair, 16)`), or you can feed the 6-char `bytes` you already have into, say, `struct.unpack('>HHH')`. Whatever you need to do is pretty easy once you know exactly what you want to do.

Finally, if you're trying to parse CSS or HTML, things like `red` or `rgb(1, 2, 3)` are also valid colors. Do you need to handle those? If so, you'll need something a bit smarter than this. The first thing to do is look at the spec for what you're trying to parse, and work out the rules you need to turn into code. Then you can write the code.

Comment: Thanks, this was along the lines of what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

The following would match a hex RGB string:

```
import re

_rgbstring = re.compile(r'#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}$')

def isrgbcolor(value):
    return bool(_rgbstring.match(value))
```

This only returns `True` if a string starting with `#` followed by exactly 6 hex digits is passed in.

Demo:

```
>>> isrgbcolor('#FAF0E6')
True
>>> isrgbcolor('#FAF0')
False
>>> isrgbcolor('FAF0E6')
False
>>> isrgbcolor('#NotRgb')
False
```

If you want to support the 3-digit CSS format as well, update the pattern:

```
_rgbstring = re.compile(r'#[a-fA-F0-9]{3}(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{3})?$')
```

This matches a hash followed by 3 hex digits, plus an optional 3 extra digits.

Comment: Strings like #FFF are also valid hex color values in CSS.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: I see no mention of CSS here; I'll add an alternative pattern to match either 3 or 6 digits.

Comment: @SimeonVisser: It's really up to the OP to specify the format he wants. Is it exactly 6 hex characters? 3N hex characters for any int N? Anything CSS will accept? And, if the latter, CSS also accepts `red` as a color. Do we need to handle that?

Comment: It is 6 hex characters.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the most simplest way. This regex will notice the `P` doesn't belong in the HEX.

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

hex = '#f8Ed90P'

pprint(re.findall('[^#0-9a-fA-F]', hex))
```

..so if there is something in the result of `re.findall` there's something wrong with your HEX structure.

This code resulted in:

```
macbook-pro:Desktop allendar$ python3 test.py
['P']
```

This code has the flaw that the hash-deck can be anywhere, which of course isn't right.

You might just want to check the hash-deck at the beginning of the string so the regex is easier to discern. Afterwards just only check if the other characters are conform to the characters allowed in your regex check.